# Retrieve JSON data from underscore template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm pretty new to using Backbone and Underscore..well Web Development in general. 
I'd like to learn how to retrieve individual "model" data on-click from this template format to populate a pop-up modal. Any direction is much appreciated!

Currently, I have a list of projects that is rendered  by passing my collection into this template and not using an individual view for each model item. I'm wondering how I can retrieve each project's data to populate a modal on-click.

I've tried getting the html data from e.currentTarget.html but I get undefined

```
  <% _.each(collection, function(model){ %>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption">
      <h3><a href= <%= model.url %>><%= model.caption %></a></h3>
    </div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src= <%= model.image %> alt=<%= model.alt %>/>
  </div>
  <h3 class="project-title text-center"><%= model.title %></h3>
  </div><%});%>
```

I had thought about following the method used in the [To-Do List](http://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/) example by Addy Osmani, but I am trying not to have to define a View for the collection of items and a View for the individual models. I can see how this method would be able to assign a click listener for the individual models and pass that model to the modalView render, but again, trying not to do it this way (if possible).

Here is an example of the data

```
{
    "projects": [{
        "title": "Portfolio Website",
        "caption": "My Showcase",
        "dates": " ",
        "url": "https://google.ca",
        "description": "Lorem Etc Etc",
        "image": "picture.jpeg",
        "alt": "Portfolio Image"
    }, {
        "title": "Online Resume",
        "caption": "Learn About Me!",
        "dates": " ",
        "url": "resume.com",
        "description": "Look at my resume",
        "image": "resume.jpeg",
        "alt": "Resume Image"
    }, {
        "title": "Project",
        "caption": "Coming Soon",
        "dates": " ",
        "url": "",
        "description": "Lorem I Don't know what comes after Lorem",
        "image": "picture.jpeg",
        "alt": "Image"
    }]
}
```

This is the Collection and View I'm using

```
    app.projectCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: app.projectDetails,

        url: '/profile.json',

        parse: function(attrs){
            return attrs.projects;
        }
    });

    var projects = new app.projectCollection();
    projects.fetch();


// View
app.portfolioView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.portfolio-body',

    projectTemplate: template('portfolio-template'),

    initialize: function(options){

        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);

    },

    events: {
        'click .portfolio-item': 'showModal' // listen for click to show modal
    },

    showModal: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        modalView.render(); // render the modal
        // console.log("clicked" + e.currentTarget.attr('caption'));

    },

    render: function(){ // projects render just fine
        this.$el.html(this.projectTemplate({collection: this.collection.toJSON()})); // pass in collection data for template to iterate though projects 

        return this;
    }
});

var portfolioView = new app.portfolioView({collection: projects}); // pass in JSON

// Modal View
app.modalView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    className: 'modal fade',

    modalTemplate: template('modal-template'),

    attributes: {
        tabindex: '-1',
        role: 'dialog'
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.modalTemplate()).modal();

        return this;
    }
});

var modalView = new app.modalView();
```

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: it'll be easier to help you if you share `app.projectDetails`, `template` method etc (in short a working demo of what you've so far)... right now if we try to run this code we get errors starting from app not defined... see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to have a link to your model inside template. But we can only have html there. The solution will be to have some unique id for each model.

You can add `id` to all your models, put it in the template like this

`<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item" data-id="<%= model.id %>">`

get this id in event handler

```
var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
```

and [get](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get) model from collection by this id

```
var model = this.collection.get(id);
```

---

By the way, I highly recommend you to try [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/), it is super nice view level extension for Backbone.